# How to assign Static IP based on MAC Address using powershell/script in Windows?

Tags: wmi, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to write up a script to assign static IP based on mac addresses, as I am having trouble with "USB to ethernet" adapters lose it's IP settings and assign to different interface Names.

I am running on windows 10 environment and have found a wmi script online that I think might work.

**Code I am using:**

*wmic nicconfig where macaddress="0F:98:90:D6:42:92" call EnableStatic ("192.168.1.1"), ("255.255.255.0")*

**Error output:** 
"Invalid format.
Hint:  =  [, ]."

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

`$netAdapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.MACAddress -eq '0F:98:90:D6:42:92'}`

`$netAdapter.EnableStatic("192.168.1.1", "255.255.255.0")`